# Excluding spaces and punctuation from selection text

Tags: vba, ms-word

I wonder if there is anyway to exclude space and puntuation from a selection text in a MS Word VBA script?

For example, this script:

```
Sub MakeBoldViolet()
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
With ActiveDocument.Range
  With .Find
    .ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.ClearFormatting
    .Replacement.Font.Bold = True
    .Replacement.Font.ColorIndex = wdPink
    .Replacement.Font.Size = 14
    .Text = Selection.Text
    .Replacement.Text = "^&"
    .Forward = True
    .Wrap = wdFindContinue
    .Format = True
    .Execute Replace:=wdReplaceAll
  End With
End With
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
```

Thank you for your time and effort by the way!

Comment: .MatchWholeWord=True?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could add:

```
.IgnorePunct = True
.IgnoreSpace = True
```

to the code to make it ignore spaces & punctuation in what is *found* (i.e. If the Find expression is for 'Nunc viverra imperdiet enim.', expressions like 'Nunc viverra.   imperdiet enim. ' will also be matched.

For the selection itself, you might use:

```
.Text = Trim(Selection.Text)
```

to eliminate before/after spaces, but what is supposed to happen if your selection spans multiple words, sentences, commas, etc.?

Comment: Thanks for this response. It is actually very helpful! I could just create a different script for such occasional cases where I would need exra characters in my selection --I think.